# How do I get to the shell on ubuntu tablet?

Tags: tablet

Just got my brand-new Aquaris M10 ubuntu edition - but I don't seem to get beyond the few apps that are on the left-hand menu. How do I get to the shell? How do I start sshd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my Aquaris M10 today as well and figured our how to start the shell:

- slide in the Launcher bar by swipe in from the left and click the big
  orange icon
- slide in "Manage" by swipe in from the bottom
- click on Apps and there you'll find the "Terminal"

To make Terminal icon sticky in Launcher bar, tap and hold Terminal icon until a sub menu opens and stickt it.

I also struggled with sshd and all solutions I found in Internet were too hacky and didn't work. But I found out, how to get sshd running:

To start sshd in Aquarius M10 enter these commands in Terminal:

```
sudo su
ssh-keygen -A
mkdir /var/run/sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

Then connect from a computer in same network to your Aquarius M10 by typing:

```
ssh phablet@192.168.1.153
```

...and you should be connected. Replace the IP address above with your M10's IP address.

Edit: I figured out, that the tablet only accepts ssh connections while Terminal is the active application on tablet. But the good thing is, even when in standby, sshd works.

Comment: Is there no need to (unlike Desktop) to install the `openssh-server` package?

Comment: Also, adding a `&` at the end of the `/usr/bin/sshd` command will run it even when the Terminal is closed (assuming the Terminal on Phone has `bash`).

Comment: Actually seems I have to install terminal from ubuntu store.

Comment: I am getting somewhat frustrated at the seemingly total lack of documentation for the tablet. Right now I am stuck at failing to log in over ssh, with the dreaded "Permission denied (publickey)" message...

Comment: Oh, and I seem to have sshd in /usr/sbin

Comment: OK, so seems that if you start sshd the proper way, with "service ssh start", it runs sshd with the option "-o PasswordAuthentication=no".  Manually starting sshd works OK.

Comment: I have to say I got the tablet in the mistaken assumption that it would be "native" ubuntu on it - seems it is android with an user-facing ubuntu top layer.